# PHP Fatal error: imap_headerinfo(): Address buffer

Tags: php

I am facing issue, when my `cron` is run. This is my error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  
imap_headerinfo(): Address buffer overflow.
```

Comment: It is not possible to provide any help without any information. You need to show the code where the error happens and explain what you're doing in the script

Comment: This calls for some code. I don't think we can guess it from just the error message.

Comment: Hm. I can't seem to find my crystal ball...

Comment: @elusive I *told* you you shouldn't put it into the dishwasher.

Comment: @Pekka: You are a genius! Found it there. Here comes the next problem: My _crystal ball_ is confused, too!

Comment: @elusive Wow. @Ergo Summary must have one of the new "Clearsight 3000" crystal balls: Check out his answer.

Comment: @Pekka: Incredible! I never had the chance to see one at work. Really stunning magic going on here.

Comment: lol.  I'm getting the same error with 500+ recipients.

Comment: I've just received the error after running the program for 8 hours, so it's almost certainly nothing code related. Luckily Ergo Summary knew how to behave with a newbie. If you haven't got anything nice to say then don't bother commenting. You ought to be ashamed of yourselves.

Answer (score 5):

It is due to an excessive number of email addresses in the cc section - most likely as a result of recieving a badly formed (purposely) spam email.

Use some error handling to recognise when imap_headerinfo() fails and skip over the message/output a spam/suspicious/error record.

Source:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50977

Comment: There is no other way to resolve this...can we remove cc address information from imap_header?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a bug with the c-client (imap_header source library).  Ensure that you have recently updated your c-client (also known as your libc-client). You will want a post 2008 update of the software.  Look here for more information: http://www.washington.edu/imap/