# Is there a way to filter incoming emails with large headers on microsoft exchange?

Tags: php, exchange-server, filtering, imap, email-client

I have a PHP IMAP based component which fetches emails from MS Exchange, its working fine on my UBUNTU dev machine, but the code faces this error on centOS based production server which has a lower version of both php and libc-client than my dev machine.

Fatal error: imap_headerinfo() [http://php.net/function.imap-headerinfo'>function.imap-headerinfo]: Address buffer overflow in /apps/app/releases/20130906105611/controllers/components/imap.php on line 359

The problem is that I cant upgrade Production Environment, so i dont want to recieve emails with large headers, most probably which has too may emailids in to, cc or bcc part of incoming emails.
Is there a way to set up this kind of filter on MS Excahnge.

Comment: there's a [Stack Overflow question already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134228/php-fatal-error-imap-headerinfo-address-buffer) with a similar issue. But it seems like they pointed to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50977 but never has been resolved.

Comment: That's why i want to create filter on MS exchange.

Comment: $overView = imap_fetch_overview($imapStream, $messageId, FT_UID);
$Mail = imap_header($this->imapStream, $msg_number));    I don't know what happened but calling imap_header or imap_headerinfo just after fetching overview not giving that error.